# part of a c code I am trying to understand?

Tags: c, algorithm

We have the following part of code.We have used linked lists.I have the following questions.

```
void   printData         (struct node* p) {
    if (p == NULL)
        return;
    printf("%d - %s %s\n", p->r, p->firstname, p->lastname);
    printf("\ne-Mail:\n-------\n");
    printMail(p->email);
    printf("\nTelephone:\n--------\n");
    printNr(p->number);
    printf("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
    printData (p->next);
```

1)I understand we have created a node structure where p is a variable pointer to node.Since the list is initally empty p== NULL because p is pointing anywhere.Now what does return do in this case?

2)`printf("%d - %s %s\n", p->r, p->firstname, p->lastname);`

Note : r is a variable where is stored the times a contact is searched. I dont understand what does  `%d - %s %s\n"` mean ? I have studied C and I know what %d and % s mean individually but not like this? What about

```
p->r, p->firstname, p->lastname) .
```

Why is the pointer pointing to the number of times a contact is searched and then pointing at firstname,lastname?

3)What does `~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~` mean?

Comment: Compile the entire code with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) then **use a debugger** to run it step by step.

Comment: Where are you learning C from? It seems you need to brush up on some fundamentals! :-)

Comment: Are you sure that this `printData()` function is where you want your recursion? I would tend to think that the function for walking the whole list would be kept separate from the function for printing a single node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)

> Now what does return do in this case?

It terminates the function, returning back to the caller without continuing for the rest of the function.

(2)

> what does  %d - %s %s\n" mean ?

You said you know what each means individually, this is just a string, containing first an integer, then a dash, then two strings, and a new line. Each of %d,%s is doing what it would have done individually.

The `p->r, p->firstname, p->lastname` part means what will be placed in the respective `%d,%s,%s` - the first `%d` will be replaced with `p->r`, the first `%s` will be replaced with the string held in `p->firstname`, and the last `%s` will be replaced by the string in `p->lastname`.

(3)

> What does
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ mean?

Nothing, it's just a part of a string to be printed - there is no syntatic means for it.
The line

```
printf("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
```

Just prints on console the line:

> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: @user3543012 I explained it in pretty details, have a look at part (2) and ask if you don't understand anything in the explanation.

Comment: Im going to choose this as best answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

- `Now what does return do in this case?`

  Return will simply return from the function if `p` is `NULL`.
- `I dont understand what does  %d - %s %s\n" mean ?`

  `%d %s %s\n` is for printing your structure variables which are p->r, p->firstname and p->lastname respectively.And `\n` is for new line.
- `What does ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ mean?`

  This will simply output

  `~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

  on screen.

Answer (score 0):

for the second part , see below :

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
printf("%d - %d", a, b);
```

will generate the out put :

```
5 - 10
```

Comment: That output will happen only when *stdout* becomes flushed!

Comment: yes @BasileStarynkevitch, when stdout _is_ fflushed

Answer (score 0):

`p->r`, `p->firstname`, `p->lastname`

in your code means `p` is not a structure, but a pointer to a structure.

generally structure elements are accessed using (`.`) dot notation,
but in case of pointer to structure you need `->`

Answer (score 0):

[1] Return exits the function and does not print anything because there-s nothing to print.

[2] printf is a function that allows you to print different formats: integers, strings, ... when %d it means that the integer will be printed in characters, %S it's a string etc. In your case:

first %d will print the characters of the integer r in the structure p,

second %s will print the string in firstname in the structure p,

third %s will print the lastname in the structure p

[3] About the ~~~~ symbols: This will print a kind of line to separate the text printed from the next thing you may print.

Hope this helps.